# How to run Ruby on Rails on App Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-app-engine

There seems to be several technology demos such as http://rails-primer.appspot.com/ on how to run Rails on App Engine. What would be the easiest way to run Rails on App Engine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because [Google App Engine only allows Python and Java code](http://code.google.com/appengine/), your only option would be to use [JRuby on Rails](http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/JRubyOnRails).

There are several tutorials on running JRoR with GAE:

- http://olabini.com/blog/2009/04/jruby-on-rails-on-google-app-engine/
- http://www.railsinside.com/news/265-how-to-use-rails-on-google-app-engine-thanks-to-jruby.html
- http://jruby-rack.appspot.com/